# Combining two networks

Tags: networking, router, mode

I have two routers at home, each one is connected to a different modem.
So let's say, **Router A** is connected to **Modem A**, and **Router B** is connected to **Modem B**.

What I want to do is that I want all computers, no matter which router they're connected to, to be in the same network.

**Meaning:** If **Computer A** is connected to **Router A**, it uses **Modem A** for internet, BUT it has access to **Computer B** which is connected to **Router B** and is using **Modem B** for internet.

My question is: How should I conifg my routers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a home-setup (ADSL for example?).

Of course there are several possibilities (with different security implications).

An easy way is: configure the routers as if they would serve the same network (but give them different IPs). You can check if it works by connecting everything to router A only (should work), then router B only (should also work, while all equipment gets IPs from the same network range).

In the final step you connect everything to one network. But before that, configure the DHCP-servers on the routers to hand out IPs from a different ranges. E.g. if the network is 192.168.10.*, tell one to hand out 192.168.10.20-40 and the other ....41-60.

Afterwards you might want to influence, which equipment prefers which router (they can’t easily use both!). If you don’t do this, then when the attached computers start, they ask for DHCP-served IPs. Both servers (in the routers) will offer one, and the computers will pick one or the other. As the offer includes the corresponding router as default gateway, this not-so-random choice of the computer decides which router it picks.

To solve this: you can manually configure IPs (and DNS?) on the equipment, e.g.: 192.168.10.61/24 with default gateway 192.168.10.2 or 192.168.10.1 (or whatever you gave router A/B).

Comment: thanks alot for your fast reply.
but shouldn't I connect the routers ? does it matter how ?

Comment: Yes, you should connect the routers. As I said: everything to one network. – One way is with a cable.

Comment: I connected the routers. One of them is set to 192.168.10.1 and the other is 192.168.10.2 and I configured the ranges.
But when I connect to one of the routers with my computer, BOTH of them become my compueter's "default gateway"! Is there a way to fix this, other than manually config all my devices?

Comment: Does the Internet connection work? If yes, then no need to act on it. – What operating system do we talk about?

Comment: Further, which device do you want to go through which router to reach the Internet?

Comment: Yes, the internet connection works. But it works through 192.168.10.1, it's probably the primary gateway. Windows and iOS. I want devices that are connected to 192.168.10.2 to use THAT exact ip as default gateway, not 192.168.10.1

Comment: Well, devices are connected to both (directly and indirectly), but I get your point. – Now the key to success is to influence which device picks up which router’s DHCP offers. This depends a lot on the routers. One way is to setup a DHCP-server (on another machine) and switch the two in the two routers off. Another chance is to “block” or “filter” some computers from one router or the other. Please check their possibilities. It is important, that they a) don’t get DHCP-offers from the wrong router, or b) that they don’t accept it (configuration on the computer).